# Como obter issues através da API REST Redmine

Tags: php, api, rest, redmine

Utilizando a API do [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) utilizando o wrapper do [Kevin Saliou](https://github.com/kbsali/php-redmine-api), estou tentando obter as [issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) de um determinado projeto porém não está sendo retornado corretamente, tanto as issues `open` quanto as `closed` estão incorretas.

```
    $client = Yii::$app->redmine->connectRedmine();

    $issues = $client->api('issue')->all([
        'project_id' => 'id5-cli-portal',
        'status_id' => 'closed',
        'sort' => 'created_on:desc,status:desc'
    ]);
```

Quando o parâmetro `status_id` é passado como `closed`, é retornado uma quantidade fixa de 25 elementos para qualquer projeto utilizado.

No exemplo do projeto acima, ele contém o seguinte:

> Funcionalidade: 15 abertas / 86
>
> Suporte: 1 aberta / 5
>
> Manutenção: 7 abertas / 61
>
> Erro: 3 abertas / 20
>
> Pesquisa de Satisfação: 0 aberta / 0

E é  retornado: `16 open issue` / `25 closed issue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A API já retorna uma chave/valor com o total de resultados:

```
$issues['total_count'];
```